# Macos Swift Print pdf file to a printer Programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I could not find any Swift developer reference for "Printing files to a Printer" in Mac OS. I know there is a way to do this task using CUPS command line.

I am searching for Swift functions to send a pdf file to printer. Any little help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to do the same.. This is a link to an old question that we may find useful... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139386/mac-os-x-print-directly-from-file-url`